# How is this notation defined in strong markov property?

Tags: probability, notation

Let $F$ be a natural filtration associated with a markov Chain $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ let's say every $X_n$ is from $\Omega$ to E, let $G$ be a $\sigma(X_n, n\geq 0)$ measurables positive or integrable function. Let $\tau$ be a stopping time adapted to F.Let's notate $\theta$ a shift operator.

Then we have the markov property :
$$\mathbb{E}[1_{T<\infty} G \circ\theta_\tau|F_\tau](x)=1_{T<\infty}\mathbb{E_{P(.|X_0=X_\tau(x))}}[G],\forall x \in \Omega$$
(If i wrote it wrong i'll be happy to have corrections)

**what i would like to know is how to deal with the $\tau$ notation in the left hand part , as $\mathbb{E}[1_{T<\infty} G \circ\theta_\tau|F_\tau]$ is defined to be a random variable , "entering the x" in the expression seems delicate to me , but i don't get how is defined $\theta_\tau$ as $\tau$ is a random variable and so , needs to be evaluated i think.Also in the right hand side i didn't evaluated $\tau$ so it might be incorrect.**